# Can Total Derivative of Quantity Give Partial Derivative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

While reading a paper on oscillating water column by David Dorrell and others it was given for the water height:

$$\sum F = \frac{d}{dt}P$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}P = \frac{d}{dt} (\rho_s\eta_1A_1\frac{d\eta_1}{dt})$$

Where the $\eta_1$ is the height of the water in the chamber and $\rho_s$ and $A_1$ are the density of water and area for the chamber.

If I calculate the RHS of the above equation I expect to get the following (obviously $\rho_s$ and $A_1$ are constant):

$${\rho_s }A_1  ((\frac{d\eta_1}{dt})^2 + \eta_1(\frac{d^2\eta_1}{dt^2}))$$

But the paper has it as :

$${\rho_s }A_1  ((\frac{d\eta_1}{dt})^2 + \eta_1(\frac{\partial^2 \eta_1}{\partial t^2}))$$

How did the second term end up in partial derivative and not total derivative?

Comment: Link to paper? Which page?

Comment: I think the mathematical outcome would be the same regardless of which one you write, because partial derivatives are just generalizations of derivatives for more than one variable.

Comment: Maybe it’s a typo?

Comment: It's not the same in general, hence the question...

Comment: The paper is given to me and it is titles as "A multichamber Oscillating Water Column Using Cascaded Savonius Turbines" By David Dorreell, Min-Fu Hsieh and Chi-Chien Lin and at the 4th page the equation 16 states that.

Comment: It is not typo and it is written in other parts of the paper too.

Comment: $\eta_1$ is the height of the water inside the column and I think it is only regular $h$ that we use in ordinary mechanics exercises.

Comment: Sorry to say but having now had a quick look at the paper, I think you'll have to find out the exact reasons yourself, in the next line they switch approximations anyway, maybe look at the sources they cite in which they developed the theory (they say that in the paragraph you quoted). But be assured it's not sone math trick you just don't get, in fluid dynamics you really use a lot of approximations and linearisatios and so on, that results in this kind of stuff. Sorry for not being much help

Answer (score -1):

It's the same thing:

$df(t,x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt +\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dx$

$d^{2}f(t,x)=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial t^{2}}dt^{2} +2\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial t\partial x }\,dtdx+\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}dx^{2}$

$\frac{d^{2}f(t,x)}{dt^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial t^{2}} +2\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial t\partial x }\,\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{dx^{2}}{dt^{2}}$

if: $x=0\,\; $  (i.e. the function only depends on one variable)

$\frac{d^{2}f(t,x)}{dt^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial t^{2}} $

which can be obtained directly : $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt=f'dt$

Comment: so take the formula without this condition .

Comment: If it is the same then why in one term it is total derivative and the other is partial?

Comment: My answer was based on the data, why go into mathematical details? if this is the case, see for example: higher mathematics of V.Smirnov volume I or G.Chilov mathematical analysis, functions of a real variable, 1st part, ....

Comment: It is the same thing with different notations !

Comment: besides, it's from Material derivative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative

Comment: We can read: "the material derivative is actually a special case of the total derivative[9]"

Comment: But in fluid dynamics $\mathbf x$ is usually a function of a time dependent path, meaning it's not just coordinates, you seem to assume mixed derivatives of $ x_i  $ vanish, which they don't generally, just look at the Navier–Stokes equation for an example. Do you see what I mean?